# Muliple SELECT in stored procedure with parameters

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm begginer to stored procedures so i start with explanation what i'm trying to achive. 
I've got excel app to fetch data from SQL server. I got 6 sql SELECT statements done in a loop with changing parameters. 
I'v already managed to change one SQL into stored procedure and it's working.

```
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO
 CREATE PROCEDURE Test
     @itm nvarchar(20) = 0 
 AS
 BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT ISNULL(SUM(T.[some_field]),0) as [Sum]
    FROM [some_table] AS T, [some_other_table] AS F, [some_other_table2] AS I
    WHERE T.[field] = 1 AND I.[field] = @itm AND
    F.[field] = T.[field] AND F.[field] = I.[field]
 END
```

When i got this first one to work i started to wonder if it's possible to put all 6 SELECT queries into one stored procedure? 
All queries results in one field which is sum of quantities. 
All queries takes at least one parameter.
At the end i'd like to recive one record with 6 fields which i can simply put in excel by `Range("A1").copyfromrecordset rst` 

 instead of creating 6 different stored procedures for each SELECT 
Will it be as simple as just put one SELECT after another? 
And what about parameters? If parameter is same for 2 queries should it be named same in both?

Comment: I would use `UDF` for that instead of `SP`

Comment: @Sami: UDF's are fine if inline table valued, otherwise avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return all 6 fields from one stored procedure. At the most basic level the way to do that would be something like:

```
SELECT
    (
        SELECT ISNULL(SUM(T.[some_field]),0) as [Sum]
        FROM [some_table] AS T, [some_other_table] AS F, [some_other_table2] AS I
        WHERE T.[field] = 1 AND I.[field] = @itm AND
        F.[field] = T.[field] AND F.[field] = I.[field]
    ) Field1
    ,
        (
            -- Another query
        ) Field2
    , etc.
```

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for. Many thanks